# C# Can Not Access public member of Form from Parent Class

Tags: c#, winforms, applicationcontext

I am trying to add an event handler in a Class that refers to an event of a Form Control which is instantiated within that Class. All classes exist within the same namespace.

The program is based on an `ApplicationContext` forms application. Within `static void Main()` in `Program.cs`

```
CustomApplicationContext applicationContext = new CustomApplicationContext();
Application.Run(applicationContext);
```

Within the `public class CustomApplicationContext`

```
public class CustomApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
    //create the application form
    Form appForm;

    public CustomApplicationContext() 
    {
        InitializeContext();

        //create instance of appForm
        appForm = new AppForm();

        //subscribe event handler to form closing event
        appForm.FormClosing += form_FormClosing; //this works fine

        //subscribe event handler to form control click event
        appForm.someToolStripMenuItem.Click += form_Click; //doesn't compile

        //can't even find appForm.someToolStripmenuItem in code completion!
    }

    void form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    void form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And from within the `public partial class AppForm` in `AppForm.Designer.cs` which is generated by the designer, where I have made the control modifier `public` and I have made the class `public`

```
public partial class AppForm  //note that I made this public
{
    ...

    this.someToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();

    ...

    // 
    // someToolStripMenuItem
    // 
    this.someToolStripMenuItem.Name = "someToolStripMenuItem";
    this.someToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(178, 22);
    this.someToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Some Item";

    ...

    public System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem someToolStripMenuItem;
}
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? When I type `appForm.`,  `someToolStripMenuItem` doesn't even appear in the code completion box, as if it were inaccessible in the context - however `appForm` is accessible, and `someToolStripMenuItem` is `public`.

Comment: So the class is public, but is the member public as well? Lowercase names usually point out non-public variables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll update this in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler thinks `appForm` is a `Form` and not an `AppForm` because of the way you're declaring it:

```
Form appForm;
```

Either try changing the declaration to `AppForm appForm;` or cast it like:

```
((AppForm)appForm).someToolStripMenuItem.Click += form_Click;
```

Comment: Both Juan and @jmcilhinney are perfectly correct, Juan got there about 30 seconds earlier.

Comment: @khargoosh, actually, I was in about 20 seconds before Juan, but what matters is that you got the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `appForm` field is declared as type `Form`.  The `Form` class has no member named `someToolStripMenuItem`.  You need to declare your field as type `AppForm` in order to access members of that type.